# How can I reset audio settings to the original / default mode?

Tags: sound, microphone, volume-control

I messed up the audio settings and now I can’t use Skype because the computer doesn’t “listen” to the microphone (plugged or not). I can hear, but they can not hear me, as if my microphone is off, but it is not.
I used Pulse Audio Volume Control to try to record the computer sound using Audacity, but I only got the problem described.
Is there a way to reset the audio settings to the original mode (ubuntu 18.04.4)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the issue is strictly related to pulseaudio settings, yes resetting it will do the trick.
Simply delete the configuration files and restart pulseaudio :

```
rm -f ~/.config/pulse/*
sudo killall pulseaudio
# daemon(s) will restart imediately
```

More information : https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/

Comment: Thanks @cmak.fr worked!

Comment: Worked for me, thanks

Comment: @cmak.fr Thanks, it worked 

Comment: You may also need to remove file `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` if your audio system has stored the messed up state at ALSA level. Otherwise the OS will restore the same config after the reboot.