# No Desktop Audio in OBS Studio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, obs-studio

I have installed the very latest OBS 26.1.1 on my Ubuntu 20.10 system (64-bit) via the official PPA.

However, no matter what I do, I cannot get the Deskop Audio channel to work, even though everything else works perfectly. No sound at all can be captured in the Desktop Audio. On Windows 10, everything works fine and I can get it to work no problem.

There is nothing wrong with my hardware, and every other audio application works perfectly. It is only the Desktop Audio in OBS where nothing comes through.

Can someone help me?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try the default `obs-studio | 26.0.2+dfsg1-1 | groovy/universe` for your release, if you needed the latest, `obs-studio  26.1.2-35-gbb6b1e53f  snapcrafters` which would have been my choices (over adding a 3rd party PPA, esp. on a *standard* release you'll have to *release-upgrade* rather soon)

Comment: I have tried the default, and I have tried the snap, in addition to the PPA. Nothing works.

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue. The monitor on my soundcard was muted in Pulseaudio Volume Control, also known as `pavucontrol`

Simply install Pulseaudio Volume Control from the Software app, or use `sudo apt install pavucontrol`

Then run it, go to the Input Devices tab, and then check if the monitor of your sound card is unmuted.

I don't know why it was unmuted, but after trying about a hundred things, I tried checking my pulseaudio settings and this fixed it.

[image]

Comment: If Monitor Section isn't available, make sure to
select `All Input Devices` in bottom right, because for some reasons, my default is `All Except Monitors`

Answer (score 3):

## I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 20.10  and OBS

I could not get the desktop audio no matter what I tried.
It seemed like something was bugged because the microphone audio could be recorded just fine.
So I googled "Reset audio ubuntu" and it came up with this:

```
rm -f ~/.config/pulse/*    # This resets Ubuntu's audio settings to its default values
sudo killall pulseaudio    # This kills all instances of pulseaudio
# daemon(s) will restart imediately
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259763/914580)

Now it works just fine.
I can not tell what the problem really was, but it took me hours to fix it.
I hope this might help someone.