# My speakers are stuck in the Volume Over-Amplification mode..!

Tags: sound, speakers

**Two weeks ago, I have tried and activated the volume over-amplification mode, I did not like it, so I deactivated it, but the speakers are stuck in this mode, the sound is very bad and I can not hear anything from it...!
anyone can help me, please ??  **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulseaudio runs your system sound settings. You can bypass Pulseaudio by using ALSA which works behind the scenes.

Install the `alsa-utils` package by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install alsa-utils
```

Then, run the following command:

```
alsamixer
```

[image]

First, use the arrow keys (left and right) to navigate to **Auto Mute** and use the up or down arrow key to disable Auto Mute.

Then, press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Next, use the Master, Speaker, or PCM volume to change your volume. If I'm not mistaken, I believe you can use the Master volume to attenuate PulseAudio volume in the background. However, sometimes PCM serves this function.

Additionally, if you use a separate sound card or if you use an external device for volume, you can press <kbd>F6</kbd> to select a different sound device.

Please let me know if there are any problems or if this doesn't work.

Comment: I forgot to mention something. If any volume indicator shows **MM** at the bottom (to indicate Mute), you can press the M key to mute or unmute. When not on mute, it should show **00** in green.

Comment: I have changed the Alsamixer settings but nothing changed, the strange thing that I have a dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu, I have tried the OVER-AMPLIFICATION for couple of seconds on Ubuntu and the speakers stuck in this mode, when I open the windows days ago I found the same issue, the speakers are not clear like before, I hope the speakers are not broken down :( @mchid

Comment: @MohamedHesham I would check to see if there is a setting in BIOS for HD sound or something. Also, check [this method to reset your pulseaudio settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259763/167115). If this works, I'll add it to my answer and close this as a duplicate of the other question. Another option would be to log into guest mode to see if the problem persists there.

Comment: @MohamedHesham As for the F5 key, it looks like the key is not recognized. Sometimes there is a Fn key or another keyboard setting that switches the function keys between functions (like volume and screen brightness). See if there is a Fn key lock. Also, there may be a key you need to press simultaneously to make the key work as F5.

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed unfortunately :(, I think my speakers are broke down ((