# USB audio causing MPV to desync sound

Tags: sound, usb

I'm having a really weird audio problem after reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04 on a machine where everything was previously working. MPV will play videos with a noticeable audio desync. Seeking causes the video to slow down for 2-3 seconds and the audio massively desyncs.

I can fix this by using the settings GUI to switch the audio device to the built in TV speakers through HDMI, playing the speaker test sound, then switching it back to the USB audio device. This is kind of silly and requires me to repeat the procedure at each startup.

I've tried resetting pulseaudio as described in [How can I reset audio settings to the original / default mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259749/how-can-i-reset-audio-settings-to-the-original-default-mode)
I also tried a bash script to switch the audio sources using pacmd, but that didn't work either.

Not sure what else to try